# Liquibase gradle plugin -> Multiple changelog files

Tags: gradle, liquibase, changelog

I am using liquibase gradle plugin and I would like to specify multiple changelog files instead of just one. The changelogs to run depends on certain conditions.

```
liquibase {
   activities {
   main {      
      changeLogFile "liquibase-changelog.xml"
      url 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world'
      username 'XXX'
      password 'XXX'
     } 
  }
 runList = 'main'
}
```

Is it possible to have an array of changelog files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the only out-of-the-box thing you can do is to make `liquibase-changelog.xml` a "master" changeLog file and include other changeLog files in it depending on the `context`.

Your `master-liqbuiase-changelog.xml` could look like this:

```
<databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <include file="liquibase-changelog-1.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true" context="your_condition_based_on_context"/>
    <include file="liquibase-changelog-2.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true" context="your_other_condition_based_on_context"/>
    <!-- other changeLog files -->
</databaseChangeLog>
```